# Import multiple XML files with different structure into Access DB (only some columns)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have to import several XML files, but they have different structures and I would like to import only certain columns from the XML files.

I use this code to import files with the same structure

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim strFile As String       'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim intFile As Integer      'File Number
    Dim strPath As String       ' Path to file folder
   
    'strPath = Me![Path]
    strPath = "D:\XML\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.XML")
    strFile = Dir(strPath & A)
    
    While strFile <> ""
       'add files to the list
      intFile = intFile + 1
      ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
      strFileList(intFile) = strFile
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    
    'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
      MsgBox "No files found"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'cycle through the list of files
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
      Application.ImportXML strPath & strFileList(intFile), 2
    Next intFile
    

    MsgBox "Import Completed"
end sub
```

How can I modify the code to import the common columns from all XML files

Comment: Cross post https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=87234

Comment: Why did you tag Excel and VBA6? I edited to remove.

Answer (score 0):

It is only my second time working with Access and xml so there is probably a better solution.  You can use the MSXML library to manipulate xml files.  For instance:

assuming an xml file from : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml
assuming you wanted to remove artists and titles

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub ImportXML()

Dim strFile As String       'Filename
    Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
    Dim intFile As Integer      'File Number
    Dim strPath As String       ' Path to file folder
    Dim xdoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60  'under tools-references add reference to msxml v6 to do it this way
        strPath = "C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.XML")
   
    While strFile <> ""
       'add files to the list
      intFile = intFile + 1
      ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
      strFileList(intFile) = strFile
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    
    'see if any files were found
    If intFile = 0 Then
      MsgBox "No files found"
      Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'cycle through the list of files
    For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
    xdoc.Load (strPath & strFileList(intFile)) 'load xml file
    trimnode xdoc, "TITLE" 'objects passed by reference
    trimnode xdoc, "ARTIST"
    xdoc.Save (strPath & "temp" & strFileList(intFile))
    Application.ImportXML strPath & "temp" & strFileList(intFile), 1
    Kill strPath & "temp" & strFileList(intFile) 'delete temp file
    Next intFile
    MsgBox "Import Completed"
    'clean up
Set xdoc = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub trimnode(xmldocument As MSXML2.DOMDocument60, nodename As String)
 Dim list As IXMLDOMNodeList
  Dim noderoot As IXMLDOMElement
  Dim parent As IXMLDOMElement
  Set noderoot = xmldocument.documentElement 'get root node
   Set list = noderoot.getElementsByTagName(nodename)
    For Each NODE In list
    Set parent = NODE.parentNode
    parent.removeChild NODE
    Next
End Sub
```

gives:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      COUNTRY       |      COMPANY       |       PRICE        |        YEAR        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USA                | Columbia           | 10.90              | 1985               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | CBS Records        | 9.90               | 1988               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USA                | RCA                | 9.90               | 1982               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Virgin records     | 10.20              | 1990               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EU                 | BMG                | 9.90               | 1997               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Polydor            | 10.90              | 1998               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | CBS                | 8.10               | 1973               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Pickwick           | 8.50               | 1990               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EU                 | Polydor            | 10.80              | 1996               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USA                | Atlantic           | 8.70               | 1987               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EU                 | Mega               | 10.90              | 1995               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USA                | Grammy             | 10.20              | 1999               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Mucik Master       | 8.70               | 1995               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USA                | Columbia           | 9.90               | 1997               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Polydor            | 8.20               | 1971               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Norway             | WEA                | 7.90               | 1996               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Island             | 8.90               | 1990               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | A and M            | 8.90               | 1988               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Siren              | 7.90               | 1987               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| UK                 | Capitol            | 8.90               | 1983               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EU                 | Medley             | 7.80               | 1983               |
  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Most helpful link I found: https://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/Lesson63.htm